# what is the advantage of b-splines over other splines?

Tags: splines

I only read that it is due to numerical reasons, e.g. on http://einspline.sourceforge.net/background.shtml, but I don't really get it.
Can someone please explain it more simple?
Is it because they are made of linear combinations? If so, why/how is this an advantage?

Comment: It might help to more narrowly define "other splines".

Comment: Splines which are not B-splines? Afaik are b-splines (together with cubic splines) mostly prefered over "others".

Comment: @Ben There are linear splines and cubic splines; either can be restricted or natural and there are other types as well.

Answer (score 12):

Splines are a large class of methods.

The method of B-splines is a simple method for taking a single covariate and expanding it such that it spans the set of all functions that are a polynomial of degree $d$ between all the given knots and $d-1$ differentiable everywhere. They are not the *only* way to achieve such an expansion of a covariate, but any other expansion will span the exact same set of functions, and B-splines have some nice numerical properties, so *if you want splines that fit those smoothness conditions*, there's not a good reason *not* to use B-splines.

B-splines are particularly popular because they are very simple and can be easily plugged into any regression model without any editing of the model to create non-linear effects without any special editing of the software.

But there's plenty of other types of splines you might want to use. To name a few:

- M-splines: splines that span strictly positive functions
- I-splines: splines that span strictly monotonic functions
- Natural splines: splines whose 1st derivative is constant outside of the knots
- P-splines: splines whose derivatives are penalized to enforce 
  smoothness (also known as smoothing splines)

Note that M+I splines are very special cases; if you want to use them, B-splines are simply not the job. Natural splines are really a subset of B-splines. P-splines have some very nice properties, but in general require special software implementations.

Comment: Just expanding a little on this excellent answer: M-splines are B-splines with only non-negative coefficients. An I-spline can be built as the integral of a M-spline. P-splines are more complex but can really alleviate the issue of choosing the right number of knots, sometimes if knots aren't spaced properly then B-splines can be ill-conditioned. P-splines usually behave better in these cases.

Answer (score 4):

The question can be reframed, to avoid ambiguity, as: What's the advantage of b-splines over the conventional splines using monomial basis?

The fundamental advantage of using B-spline representation is that the equation system for the expansion coefficients is numerically more stable than using monomial basis, which results in Vandermonde systems, which can be quite ill-conditioned.

The goal of choosing different basis functions is to improve the conditioning of the resulting linear equation system and the computational effort for determining the coefficients.